# CSS3 box shadow size by percentage

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set the box shadow size and offsets by percentage? I currently make use of such a class, but zooming-in changes its size and distance:

```
    .shadowright
    {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #454545;
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #454545;
        -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #454545;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #454545;             
    }
```

Comment: i dont understand what are you asking, if you zoom in it enlarges everything, what would you want to happen?

Comment: hmmm.. never tried using percentage to do that before. have you tried with media queries maybe?

Comment: Zooming in doesn't seem to do anything weird to me. It just scales like everything else does.

Comment: I'm trying to develop a fluid layout which scales with the browser window size. Since all the metrics are in percentages, zooming in or out does not enlarge or reduce the elements; only re-sizing the browser window would do that. But the box shadow size and distance expands and shrinks on its own when zoomed. Anyway, it seems that using EM instead of PX works quite well.

Comment: You need media queries and media specific css for that bud.

Comment: Mozilla has a very good documentation on HTML,CSS and JavaScript. Please refer the following for knowing more about box-shadow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 4):

No. As per the [W3C Specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#box-shadow):

> Computed value: any `<length>` made **absolute**; any specified color computed; otherwise as specified

Emphasis mine. Relative values (percentages) won't work.

Comment: @iSofia Good question. Short answer: no. Long answer: `EM` is scalable, but it is not relative in the same sense. `EM` is fixed to the current font-size. If you change the font-size, the `EM` is re-declared. Percentages are, by definition, always relative to something else and cannot stand on their own. In contrast, `1em` is, by default, equal to `12px` (font-size). In other words, `EM` is a variable.

Comment: You're right; thank you for that answer. It works because of a JavaScript function that re-sizes the fonts whenever the client area is re-sized. An acceptable solution nevertheless.

Comment: I need to clarify (for my own sake) that the above comment should read `16px`, not `12px`. I goofed and mixed up the default `font-size` for browsers with the font size of text documents.

Answer (score 3):

Was googling for a better solution that I had in mind, for everyone that's searching for a possible solution.

```
.shadowright
{
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 20vw; // if you want the box-shadow to equal it's width
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 1em red;
}
```

Comment: Do I misunderstand something? I know box-shadow is 20vw offset in your case, but 20vw is not equal to 20%. Why do you say "if you want the box-shadow to equal it's width"?

BTW, I think, to the original @iSofia problem, it is correct just to assign em to the box-shadow, assuming he or she wants it to be "relative to font size".

Comment: @Eric , In this case if the element is 20% of the whole width, then he made it in a way that ensures 1em equals the total size of the element (conceptually 100%). Not 20%, because 20% is the size of the element relative to its parent. Then following this logic, if you want an offset of 20% of the element on the shadow, you just use 0.2em instead. Confusing I have to admit.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found a solution (with today’s CSS though ^^):
While you can’t use percentage values, you can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) with decimal fractions.

```css
div[id^=shadow] {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-block-end: 3em;
}

#shadow-1 {box-shadow: 0 calc(.05 * 1em) 0 red;}
#shadow-2 {box-shadow: 0 calc(.25 * 1em) 0 red;}
#shadow-3 {box-shadow: 0 calc(1.5 * 1em) 0 red;}
#shadow-4 {box-shadow: 0 calc(.75 * 5px) 0 red;}
#shadow-5 {box-shadow: 0 calc(2 * 5px) 0 red;}
```

```html
<div id="shadow-1">5% of 1em</div>
<div id="shadow-2">25% of 1em</div>
<div id="shadow-3">150% of 1em</div>
<div id="shadow-4">75% of 8px</div>
<div id="shadow-5">200% of 8px</div>
```

In your case that could be

```
.shadowright
{
    --offset: 5px
    box-shadow: var(--offset) var(--offset) calc(2 * var(--offset)) #454545;             
}
```